# Expanding RAID volume on PowerEdge

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, dell-perc

I have a PowerEdge T620 and R620 with RAID5 volumes on Perc H710P controllers. Can these be expanded in place with no data loss by adding additional drives?

I have seen this demonstrated online, but it's not an option in the RAID management interface (Ctrl-R upon boot). All firmware is up-to-date, but I don't have a copy of OpenManage installed if that matters.

This is trivial on Synology NAS units, but I'm wanting to repurpose these boxes. They would end up running Windows 2019 or Debian 10 to create data shares.

If this is not possible, how about for T630, T640, or T650 servers?

Comment: Yes, and it's a well documented feature. Just use storcli.

Comment: storcli does not recognize Perc H710P controllers.